# Joining tables using wildcard and avoiding repeated columns

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to run the following query

```
create multiset volatile table newTable, no log as (
SELECT so.*, pu.*
FROM db.table1 so
left outer join db.table2 pu on so.id = pu.id
) with data primary index(id) on commit preserve rows;
```

Teradata is giving me the following error:

> [TeraJDBC 15.00.00.20] [Error 3809] [SQLState 42S02] Column 'id' is ambiguous.

Because of the index I want to create over the ID column. My question is, then, is there any way to either avoid having the joining column duplicate or to disambiguate the index?

Comment: You need to not just use select * from both tables. You'll have to specify the columns you are selecting, and alias any columns with matching names.

Comment: so and po has columns id. So in sub query you specifically give a different column names for each id column

Comment: Specifying the column names is the current approach to the problem. I'm changing it because the number of columns is pretty overwhelming and frequently changing, hence bound to err.

Comment: You approach to change the process won't work. The database cannot resolve ambiguity caused by a developer/dba/data architect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the `so.*, pu.*`, both tables got a column with the name `id` and thus you try to create a table with the same column name twice.

Change the `*` to the list of columns and either exclude `id` or add an alias, e.g. `so.id as so_id`

Comment: I'm interested in this kind of solution precisely because it avoids listing the column names: I have way too many columns and the schema changes very often so as to ensure everything's coherent.

Comment: There's no workaround, pick the table with the lower number of columns and keep the `*`for the other one...

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
with data primary index(id)
```

Which table is "id" here supposed to be from?  This is where your error is.

Comment: I realized that, what I'm asking is if there is some easy way to disambiguate the name

Comment: If "id" is from table "db.table1", then since you've already set it with the alias "so", then all you would need is "so.id", like how you've done earlier in the code.

Comment: I already tried that, the corresponding error is [TeraJDBC 15.00.00.20] [Error 3706] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error: expected something between the word 'so' and '.'.